# how to parse Pandas Dataframe into the specific sheet of macro file

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to parse 2 columns in dataframe sample below into the excel macro workbook (xlsm),

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import *
excel_path = "test.xlsm"
df.head()
HT  D   Group
0   A   BL  
1   B   7   Group D
2   C   NaN 
3   D   5   Group C
4   E   2   group A
5   F   NaN 
6   G   3   Group B
df_temp = df[['HT','D']]
```

I would like to parse df_temp into column A and B on Sheet1 of the macro file (path_excel).
I tried with the code below:

```
wb = load_workbook(path_excel,read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws['A1']
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df_temp,index=False,header=False):
    print(r)
    (ws.max_row + 1).append(r)
```

but it could not write the data from the df_temp to the macro file as I expected , Could you please help look it ?

Comment: "but it could not write the data from the df_temp to the macro file as I expected" is not a question.  Please clarify what problem you are having as well as what your desired output looks like. Since SO is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutorial service, Could you please look at it isn't a valid question either.

Comment: hi @itprorh66 , Sorry for my missing info , btw I have solved this already. Thanks for your note.

Comment: If you have a solution, please answer your own question and accept the answer.  In this way we all learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve my issue already , it just simple edit

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import *
excel_path = "test.xlsm"
df.head()
HT  D   Group
0   A   BL  
1   B   7   Group D
2   C   NaN 
3   D   5   Group C
4   E   2   group A
5   F   NaN 
6   G   3   Group B
df_temp = df[['HT','D']]
wb = load_workbook(path_excel,read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df_temp,index=False,header=False):
    ws.append(r)
wb.save(excel_path)
```

That's all. in the excel file, open_workbook event has been configured already. just use python to start this file then it could work as fine.